# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': YoutubeIframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage, youtube-iframe-api

I am rendering an iframe at the bottom of my page like this :

```
<iframe
    id="yt-iframe"
    title="xyz"
    loading="lazy"
    src=`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}?enablejsapi=1`
    frameBorder="0"
    allowFullScreen
    allow="autoplay"
  />
```

Initially the iframe is not visible on page load and user has to scroll a bit to make it visible on viewport.

I get following endless errors once the page is loaded.
**Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('') does not match the recipient window's origin ('').**

The errors would stop coming if any of these happens:

- with loading="lazy" --> the window is scrolled and the iframe is in the viewport.
- loading="eager"
- enablejsapi=0

However my requirement is that I need the loading to be "lazy" and I also need the enablejsapi=1 in order for the YoutubeIframeAPI to work (to be able to do things on state change of the player).

Would be great if anyone can suggest a fix with proper reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check the following docs

Try adding an `origin` parameter to your embed URL
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#origin

Instead of directly constructing the Iframe by yourself, consider using iframe API from youtube

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: setting origin didn't work for me ,Youtube iframe API gives me the same error.

Comment: @DeepanshuBatra, can you share a minimum repro to debug this?